# Websites to ask for specific book recommendations

Tags: discussion

Are there any websites designed for asking real people for specific book recommendations? I know there are websites where you can enter your reading preferences and have an algorithm give you recommendations, and that here on Literature Stack Exchange asking for help finding a book that you know exists but can't remember the title of is allowed; but I'm looking for a website where I can ask about a specific kind of book I'm looking for without having a particular book in mind.

If this question is off topic or would be better asked on a different Stack Exchange site, please let me know.